# Moving a LUKS encrypted POP_OS installation with boot to a new location

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, luks, pop-os

I would like to move my POP_OS! Linux installation which is encrypted with LUKS to a different Brand new SSD. (Source is nvme, target is a blank SATA SSD).

```
**Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKKW256G7                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: AD30FF2D-1139-4431-898D-2E1ABDFCA836

Device              Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    923647    921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2     923648   1126399    202752   99M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3    1126400   1159167     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4    1159168 163417441 162258274 77.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5  163418112 164483071   1064960  520M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p6  164485120 275597311 111112192   53G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p7  275597312 276549631    952320  465M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p8  317509632 319557629   2047998 1000M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p9  329797632 419909631  90112000   43G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p10 419909632 500115455  80205824 38.2G Microsoft basic data
```

Here -

1. /dev/nvme0n1p8 is the boot drive
2. /dev/nvme0n1p9 is the LUKS encrypted drive

I want to move it to the new SSD such that -

1. /dev/nvme0n1p8 becomes sda1
2. /dev/nvme0n1p9 becomes sda2
3. I want the EFI boot to use sda so that if I remove the nvme drive, the new/SATA one still boots.

How should I go about it. I have a popos livecd and can operate the command line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regardless of what is possible, I would go about this by simply re-creating the partitions from scratch. Re-installing software isn't that hard, and it will be similar to an OS version update with a clean slate. Often the installed set of software gets "cleaner" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) or [Rescuezilla](https://rescuezilla.com/) (which is a fancy GUI for Clonezilla) for that.

I've ran into a very similar situation a month ago (Pop!_OS; LUKS), and was able to successfully clone the drive.

If your destination drive's capacity is less than the source drive, you may need to shrink the partition(s) on the source beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

As unsolaci suggests, if your new disk is equal in size (or larger) than your original disk, you can use Clonezilla or Rescuezilla to achieve this.

Since you have a dual-boot Windows environment you probably boot first into the GRUB bootloader. This is ideal.

1. Boot Rescuezilla from a USB stick
2. Clone the source drive to the destination.
3. Shutdown computer and disconnect the source drive for safety
4. Confirm your newly cloned drive can boot Pop!_OS as expected
5. Reboot into Rescuezilla
6. [Use GParted to delete all the unnecessary partitions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=88&v=ribKSCX85w4&feature=youtu.be) (everything but 99MB EFI System Partition) and the Linux LUKS partition. This should be a near instantaneous operation. It may be worth rebooting POP!+_OS again here, just to confirm everything works
7. With Rescuezilla, use GParted to shift the LUKS partition to the start of the disk so there is no wasted space.
8. Reboot again to confirm Pop!_OS continues to boot.

Now you have almost achieved what you want, the final thing to do is to expand the LUKS encrypted partition to fill up the entire disk. GParted might be able to do this, but I know there are some limitations with this using GParted, so it may require command-line interface commands. I understand KDE's blivet-gui better at this.